# How to allow commentetors to get notifications on replies to their comments?

Tags: comments

Whenever someone comments on a blog post I've written, I want to reply to him as a comment. However, I'm sure that most of the time that person doesn't see my reply, because he's only subscribed to my post feed, not my comment feed (which makes sense - he's not interested in all comments that are posted to my blog).

Is there a way to help commentators be notified when someone replies to them in another comment?

Answer (score 5):

There are plugins that add option to subscribe to comments via email.

I use [Subscribe to Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/) at my blog and it works fine for me and readers, but it is very old and promised update seems totally stuck so I suggest to look for something more maintained.